# Emacs lsp update pylsp server

Tags: python, emacs

I'm trying to update the lsp server in python-mode based on the current project in order to use the correct virtualenv.

I'm doing something like this

```
(use-package python-mode
  :ensure t
  :preface 
  (defun projectile-set-lsp-venv ()
  "Set pyenv version matching project name."
  (let ((project (projectile-project-name)))
    ;; How can I update pylsp server here?
    ;;(setq lsp-pylsp-server-command (concat project "venv/bin/pylsp"))
    ))
  :init
  (add-hook 'projectile-after-switch-project-hook #'projectile-set-lsp-venv)
  )
```

But I don't find a way to update the pylsp server. Using setq lsp-pylsp-server-command is not working, I suppose because it's not reloaded.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried creating a symlink called ".venv" in the project's root directory to venv? (Not sure if it will work for what you want.)

Comment: try `lsp-workspace-restart` after changing the server command